# Will you entertain questions related to wolfram alpha here?

Tags: discussion

Will you entertain questions related to wolfram alpha here?

Comment: See the bullet points under "off-topic": https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Nope.  But many questions concerning *Wolfram|Alpha* have direct counterparts in *Mathematica*, so perhaps you can cast it as such.

Comment: You could just ask the question.  Worst that could happen is it gets closed

Comment: Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic:
Questions on Wolfram Alpha (but questions on using Wolfram Alpha within Mathematica are okay).

Comment: How might one entertain them? Serve the hors d'oeuvres?